# how to find the size of a scaled carousel image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries, carousel

I am relatively new to CSS and Bootstrap. I am trying to display justified text below a carousel and align text margins with the left and right edges edges of the image on all screen sizes. Each image is 886 × 460 pixels. When I tried `carousel-caption` it overlaid the image jamming extra text into the space above it and the text margins were not aligned with the image.

This might be a naive question but is there some other related CSS class I can use to determine the actual size of the image for any given screen size so I can align text margins with the left and right image edges ?

My code example using `carousel-caption` follows.

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="flex-grow-0 item active">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="images/pic-1.jpg" alt="ex.1">              
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow-0 item">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="images/pic-2.jpg" alt="ex.2">
            </div>    
        </div>


        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption" style="font-size: 12px; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:justify">
    <h4>Blog</h4>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the div with class `carousel-caption` inside the div `#mycarousel` and the caption should work.

If not,
 I modified the [Bootstrap code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#with-captions) like this

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="images/pic-1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
     </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/pic-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/pic-1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    </div>

     <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

Kindly review it. Hope It helps.